# Use rPi as a remote access a network drive when outside of network

Tags: networking, remote, file-sharing, file-server

In my workplace, we have a network drive/server/NAS kind of thing, and on it is stored the installation media for numerous programs. I can access this when I am connected to the network directly, however when I come home, and need to install a program, say over a weekend, there isn't a way for me to do that.

Is there a way to set up a Raspberry Pi on that network, that is set up to connect to that network drive; and then I can remotely connect to it over the internet, in order to access files stored on the network drive?

I understand that there may be a bit of a security risk involved here, being that effectively I'm opening up the internal network drive to the web, but I'm sure there'd be some way of doing it securely - or even have someone fire up the rPi whenever someone wants to connect, shutting it off again when they're done.

Comment: And you are willing to assume this risk not only for yourself and your convenience but for the entire company?

Comment: For the sake of all concerned, please take a look at the variety of VPN tutorials. For example https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-vpn-server/ There's no point in exposing yourself (so to speak) when you don't have to!

Comment: Someone would have to open up your office firewall, which is probably a bad idea. You could circumvent corporate security if they haven't locked things down by opening a connection to the outside, then coming back in through that, but this is typically a firing offense. What you really need is to get a VPN account set up that is compliant with company policy. Then, just VPN in when you need access, and let those responsible for security stay liable.

Comment: I understand that opening an internal network promotes a security risk, and I was looking for other ways to do this. A VPN run by a Pi seems like a good option, and should be secure if set up properly

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend having a conversation with your IT department about viable alternatives for access (for example getting VPN access) rather than trying to engineer out some solution yourself.
Not only can a self-engineered solution land you in some hot water (including dismissal from your job in some cases) but it provides an endpoint that may be exploited to gain access to your company network.

Consider that in order for you to reach this machine that resides on your company network than it would need to be exposed to the public internet; without this, there is no route to it.
If you can reach this endpoint directly than it also means that so can everyone else.

Should you not believe that this is a problem simply set up a machine that can be accessed from the internet, put up an SSH server on port 22, then start watching your /var/log/auth.log; that will give an idea of just how many things will find this machine and attempt to break into it.